# Show video to JPanel

Tags: java, netbeans, jpanel, jmf

I am creating a simple video player but I'm having problem to show the video file to stream in JPanel. I've created and designed a JFrame and put a square size JPanel inside the form.

Here is my codes so far:

```
package SoundsTrip;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.media.CannotRealizeException;
import javax.media.Manager;
import javax.media.NoPlayerException;
import javax.media.Player;
import javax.swing.JFileChooser;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

/**
 *
 * @author jmoreno
 */
public class VideoFrame extends javax.swing.JFrame {
    /** Creates new form VideoFrame */
    public VideoFrame() {
        initComponents();
        //this.setExtendedState(VideoFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
        this.setSize(650, 500);
    }

    /** This method is called from within the constructor to
     * initialize the form.
     * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is
     * always regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">
    private void initComponents() {

        jPanel1 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        jButton1 = new javax.swing.JButton();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        getContentPane().setLayout(null);

        javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanel1Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jPanel1);
        jPanel1.setLayout(jPanel1Layout);
        jPanel1Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGap(0, 450, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );
        jPanel1Layout.setVerticalGroup(
            jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGap(0, 330, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );

        getContentPane().add(jPanel1);
        jPanel1.setBounds(10, 10, 450, 330);

        jButton1.setText("Open Video/Movie");
        jButton1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jButton1ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });
        getContentPane().add(jButton1);
        jButton1.setBounds(470, 10, 160, 23);

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>

    private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
        // TODO add your handling code here:
        try {
            openMedia();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(SoundBytePlaying.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (CannotRealizeException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(SoundBytePlaying.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }

    public void openMedia() throws IOException, CannotRealizeException{
        JFileChooser fileChooser = new JFileChooser();
        int result = fileChooser.showOpenDialog(null);
        if(result == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION){
            URL mediaURL = null;
            try{
                mediaURL = fileChooser.getSelectedFile().toURL();
            }catch(MalformedURLException malformedURLException){
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Could not create URL for the file");
            }
            if(mediaURL != null){
                **showVideo() //some error here**
            }
        }
    }

    public void showVideo(URL mediaURL){
        Manager.setHint( Manager.LIGHTWEIGHT_RENDERER, true );

        try{
            //create a player to play the media specified in the URL
            Player mediaPlayer = Manager.createRealizedPlayer( mediaURL );

            //get the components for the video and the playback controls
            Component video = mediaPlayer.getVisualComponent();
            Component controls = mediaPlayer.getControlPanelComponent();

            if ( video != null )
                add( video, BorderLayout.CENTER ); //add video component
            if ( controls != null )
                add( controls, BorderLayout.SOUTH ); //add controls

                mediaPlayer.start(); //start playing the media clip
        } //end try
        catch ( NoPlayerException noPlayerException ){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "No media player found");
        } //end catch
        catch ( CannotRealizeException cannotRealizeException ){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Could not realize media player.");
        } //end catch
        catch ( IOException iOException ){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error reading from the source.");
        } //end catch
    }

    /**
    * @param args the command line arguments
    */
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new VideoFrame().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    // Variables declaration - do not modify
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton1;
    private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel1;
    // End of variables declaration

}
```

Many thanks to any idea and help I could get here... :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try to add your `Video and Control` components to your `jPanel1`

```
...
if ( video != null )
 jPanel1.add( video, BorderLayout.CENTER ); //add video component
if ( controls != null )
 jPanel1.add( controls, BorderLayout.SOUTH ); //add controls
...
```

Answer (score 4):

I would really suggest using [vlcj](http://code.google.com/p/vlcj/) either than JFM and showing video in canvas. vlcj is simple as pie, heres the code to get a video pane.

```
String path = "/usr/lib"; //path for the vlc libs in linux
NativeLibrary.addSearchPath ( "libvlc", path );
System.setProperty ( "jna.library.path", path );

MediaPlayerFactory factory = new MediaPlayerFactory ();
mediaPlayer = factory.newEmbeddedMediaPlayer ();
mediaPlayer.setRepeat ( false );
mediaPlayer.setEnableKeyInputHandling ( false );
mediaPlayer.setEnableMouseInputHandling ( false );

CanvasVideoSurface videoSurface = factory.newVideoSurface ( canvas );
mediaPlayer.setVideoSurface ( videoSurface );
mediaPlayer.playMedia ( "/media/path/" );
```

Answer (score 3):

just try this code :

```
if(mediaURL != null)
           {
                showVideo(mediaURL) //some error here**
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

When testing JMF based projects, be sure to use 'JMF compatible' media as might be obtained at my [media page](http://pscode.org/media/#video).  JMF is very old, and does not support many media types or CODECs used for media made recently.

Comment: What would be the best package i should use? Could you give me some idea that I might be able to look at and study... Thanks.

Comment: Freedom for Media: http://fmj-sf.net/
compatible to JMF.

If you are Windows only you can also consider the DirectShow wrapper: http://www.humatic.de/htools/dsj.htm

But no matter how you turn it, multimedia is not Java's strongsuit.

Comment: I've downloaded already the jmf folder in zip format. how to install it? why do i need to download the ffmpeg and theora. I can't really get on how to install this thing and how to download the ffmpeg and theora... thanks