# how to display a video using java?

Tags: java, media-player, jmf

I am trying to play a video with .avi format using javax.mediaplayer and here is the method

```
void open() {
    // create a file chooser
    JFileChooser fileChooser = new JFileChooser();

    // show open file dialog
    int result = fileChooser.showOpenDialog(null);

    if (result == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) // user chose a file
    {
        URL mediaURL = null;

        try {
            // get the file as URL
            mediaURL = fileChooser.getSelectedFile().toURL();
        } // end try
        catch (MalformedURLException malformedURLException) {
            System.err.println("Could not create URL for the file");
        } // end catch

        if (mediaURL != null) // only display if there is a valid URL
        {
            JFrame mediaTest = new JFrame("Media Tester");
            mediaTest.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

            MediaPlayer mediaPanel = new MediaPlayer();
            mediaPanel.setMediaLocator(new MediaLocator(mediaURL));

            mediaTest.add(mediaPanel);

            mediaTest.setSize(300, 300);
            mediaTest.setVisible(true);
        } // end inner if
    } // end outer if
}
```

The problem is whenever i run, it runs successfully and the jframe pops up but empty with no video inside it,,, any help ?

Comment: Do you have any errors showing in the console output?

Comment: no it runs successfully but the video itself does not appear

Comment: Have you tried searching for similar questions on the site? Give this a try: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5457269/show-video-to-jpanel

Comment: If you've found a solution, be sure to answer your own question below.